# Specifying geom_path by y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Struggling with specifying geom_path such that the line connection below is avoided. I want the path to be going down the y-axis alone.

Here is the dataset:

```
xer_filename    task_code   unpivot_val
DD20210630.xer  HBA-DPE-1000020 2022-08-30 08:00
DD20210725.xer  HBA-DPE-1000020 2022-08-30 08:00
DD20210830.xer  HBA-DPE-1000020 2022-08-30 08:00
DD20210919.xer  HBA-DPE-1000020 2022-02-17 08:00
DD20211104.xer  HBA-DPE-1000020 2022-01-27 08:00
DD20211128.xer  HBA-DPE-1000020 2022-04-22 08:00
DD20211226.xer  HBA-DPE-1000020 2022-07-07 08:00
```

Using ggplot and unpivot_value as date

```
library(ggplot2)
dataset$unpivot_val <- as.Date(dataset$unpivot_val, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

This is my current command:

```
ggplot(data = dataset, aes(y = xer_filename, x = unpivot_val, group = task_code,colour=task_code)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + guides(x="axis",x.sec="axis") + scale_y_discrete(limits=rev) + geom_path(aes(group=task_code))
```

Help appreciated!

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks I've put a more complex example and sample dataset

Comment: I guess I will add "with data in a usable format" to "reproducible example" next time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution was to simply remove geom_line() from my equation. Seems geom_line and geom_path must plot additive to eachother.

[image]